# Using fluentD to catch logs when the same file is created again

Tags: fluentd

I have a log file that is continuously deleted and re-created with the same structure but different data.

I'd like to use fluentD to export that file when a new version of the file is created. I tried various set of options but it looks like fluentD misses the updates unless I manually add some lines to the file.

Is this a use case that is supported by default sources/parsers?

Here is a config file is use

```
<source>
  @type tail
  tag file.keepalive

  open_on_every_update true
  read_from_head true
  encoding UTF-8
  multiline_flush_interval 1
...
</source>
```

Comment: Did you try [`refresh_interval`](https://docs.fluentd.org/input/tail#refresh_interval) with `*` in `path`?

Answer (score 0):

- Try tail plugin, but instead of specifying a path to a file, specify a path to a parent directory like `dir/*`: https://docs.fluentd.org/input/tail#path
- Try adding a datetime to filename everytime you recreate it - this will 100% force it to read all.

Comment: Thx for your response Max however it looks like solution 1 doesn't work and for the second one i don't have control on the file generation. I'll try to take a look at custom plugins